# GMSMarker custom icon not appearing according to coordinates. iOS - Swift - Google Map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

I am new to iOS platform, adding custom icon (Vehicle Icon) to GMSMarker but its not showing on map view according to coordinates, even shown in blue in color instead of its original image color.

Please check the code below:

```
func ambulanceOnMap() {
    let vehicle = UIImage(named: "mapAmbulance")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let markerView = UIImageView(image: vehicle)
    vehicleImage = markerView

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 24.9259594, longitude: 67.0844429)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.iconView = markerView
    marker.tracksViewChanges = true
    marker.map = mapView
    vehicleMarker = marker
}

//Emergency Button Tapped
@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    ambulanceOnMap()
    vehicleImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(self.vehicleImage)
}
```

Result Screenshot attached: 
[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxA1I.png)

Comment: Its showing in the top left corner because you have set marker frame on button tap.

Comment: What should be done to pointing it on Map according to coordinates? I think frame is not an issue. If I remove the frame its still shown attached to the screen, If I move the maps its moving like a spot on screen. Thanks Aaqib!